# Getting JPEG Redundant Data

Tags: c, image, jpeg, libjpeg

I am doing some project related to image compression and I need a way to save the data lost in JPEG compression (like bits per pixel..). I guess I would need to build a custom libjpeg for that. Appreciate any suggestions/help on the subject (maybe even guidance to what part to modify in the source code).

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:** To clarify myself, I am not looking into embedding hidden information. I am looking for a method to get the data lost during JPEG compression. I am also OK with getting the data lost from re-compressing a JPEG image (from 90 to 80).

Answer (score 0):

If you are in need to embed private data into JPEG bitstream, you might want to take advantage of APPn markers. There are few great things about them:

- the image will still be readable and compatible with software out there
- the format is simple enough so that you can leave libjpeg or your another favorite `JPEG` library intact, and add/read the data modifying the bitstream directly

[JPEG File Interchange Format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG_File_Interchange_Format) is using `APP0` and `APP1`, you can read the details and there are still more available markers like `APP2` which you can use for your purposes.

Comment: I am trying to get the lost data during the JPEG compression process for some research project. I need the data to be easy to work on (like bits per pixel, matrix etc.).

Comment: I see, the question is actually different. As for measuring the compression loss part, why don't you use existing JPEG compression library, and decompress compressed image and subtract it from original? This would get you the difference without need to dive into JPEG compression code?

Answer (score 0):

There's at least four steps where you can lose information in jpeg compression. I don't really know what you're getting at. If you want to measure the lost information, you can just compress/decompress and compare with the original.

I guess you want to encode RGB to standard JFIF, then you lose information in the color conversion, subsampling, after that you have to do FDCT and I don't think that is exactly reversible so you lose information in that step and then you have the quantization step. Unless you have quantization tables containing all ones you will lose information there also.

To sum it up:

1. Color conversion
2. Subsamling
3. FDCT/IDCT
4. Quantization